# How can I draw repeating horizontal lines on a chart in Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script

My goal is to create a Pine Script indicator that draws horizontal lines at every cent on the chart (0.01, 0.02, 0.03, etc up to 2.00). So far I have an indicator that I can add to the chart, but there are no visible lines. I also added inputs so that the user can draw the horizontal lines within any range they want as well as with any frequency that they want.

So far this is what I have:

```
indicator("Horizontal Lines", overlay=true)
    
TRange = input(2.00, title="Top of Range", group="Line Settings")
BRange = input(0.01, title="Bottom of Range", group="Line Settings")
Freq = input(0.01, title="Line Frequency", group="Line Settings")
LColor = input(color.blue, title="Line Color", group="Line Style")
LStyle = input(line.style_dotted, title="Line Style", group="Line Style")

for i = BRange*100 to TRange*100 by Freq
    yspot = i * 0.01
    line.new(bar_index, yspot, bar_index + 1, yspot, xloc=xloc.bar_index, extend=extend.both, color=LColor, style=LStyle, width=6)
```

I am able to add this to the chart with no errors, yet no lines are being drawn. What is the issue?

I think this is probably an issue with the line.new command and my misuse of the bar_index, but I am not sure.

This imgur is an example of what I want my outcome to look like, but you will also see that is was achieved with some very poor code that is not easily customizable. My goal is to use the new code that I pasted above that uses a for loop and inputs that the user can customize instead of just listing each value that I want a line drawn. https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1tdz.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, pinescript draw only the 50 last lines.
You can tell pinescript to draw at max 500 lines by asking it in the indicator declaration.
Then your loop must be modified a bit to give the good level to line.new.
Here is the working code :

```
indicator("Horizontal Lines", overlay=true, max_lines_count = 500)
    
TRange = input(2.00, title="Top of Range", group="Line Settings")
BRange = input(0.01, title="Bottom of Range", group="Line Settings")
Freq = input(0.01, title="Line Frequency", group="Line Settings")
LColor = input(color.blue, title="Line Color", group="Line Style")
LStyle = input(line.style_dotted, title="Line Style", group="Line Style")

for i = BRange to TRange by Freq
    line.new(bar_index, i, bar_index + 1, i, xloc=xloc.bar_index, extend=extend.both, color=LColor, style=LStyle, width=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Your knowledge is extremely helpful!